# Selenium IDE not finding an element that does exist

Tags: javascript, selenium-ide, getelementsbyclassname

Why does this not work with the Selenium IDE?

```html
<td>click</td>
<td>window.document.getElementsByClassName('bi-icon-plus-blue')[0]</td>
<td></td>
```

The element exists. If I open the console and execute it, the element element shows up. If I wrap it in console.log like so:
console.log(window.document.getElementsByClassName('bi-icon-plus-blue')[0]);

I get this interesting message that is way beyond my ken:

"Security wrapper denied access to property undefined on privileged Javascript object. Support for exposing privileged objects to untrusted content via **exposedProps** is being gradually removed - use WebIDL bindings or Components.utils.cloneInto instead. Note that only the first denied property access from a given global object will be reported."

Comment: And this does work when you run the test manually? Is it possible the element isn't loaded yet when the test is run? Did you VerifyElementExists?

Comment: No, it does not work when run manually (by this, I assume you to mean double clicking on the step in the window, or, by using the "Execute this Command"). The element has loaded. VerifyElementPresent does not detect the item.

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is incorrect. You're using javascript command. Intead try `css=.bi-icon-plus-blue`. For more information look here: http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/02_selenium_ide.jsp#locating-elements

Comment: I wanted to avoid using a css selector. I wanted an array or a collection so that I could iterate. Here's what eventually worked: `<td>click</td><td>document.getElementsByClassName('bi-icon bi-icon-plus-blue')[${myVariable}]</td><td></td>` I know of no way to do ` css=.bi-icon-plus-blue[${myVariable}]`

Comment: check out nth-of-type.